# MKMapKit tiles level of detail

Tags: ios, mkmapview

I have a problem with MKMapKit and will very appreciate, if anyone can help me.
When I'm using MKMapCamera and making 3D view, MKMapKit using tiles from different layers on one screen. It's looking awful. Here is a screenshot:

[image]

Please, help me =)

Comment: What you have tried code so far?

Comment: Well to be honest, nothing. I really don't know how can I control the layers of the map. But I pretty sure that it will be nice looking if map will use tiles from one layer.